# Fitting a model taking too long on Colab (Tensorflow) with a GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

i am following a course on TensorFlow. and while trying to fit a model on Colab with a GPU, it shows ETA: 96:45:07. usually it doesn't take this long.
The dataset is larger than i am used to work with, but it's not supposed to take this much time according to the video[image]

i was trying to fit the model, but i was not expecting it to be that long.

Comment: Do not post code as images, and include as much information as possible, you did not even mentioned how big the dataset is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input and expected output so that we can better help you better.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow :D

One of the reasons you may be seeing this is because in line 3 you are using the entirety of your train_data for your steps_per_epoch.
This means that for each of your 3 epochs, you are taking the entire length of your train data to pass through your dataset.

Would you be able to show more of your notebook or link to the video that you are using to code along?
That way I would be able to get more context for what is going on here.

**Side note:**
Generally, if you have access to a TPU, it would be faster to use than a GPU, but ultimately it boils down to how you are trying to fit your model.

Comment: Not really, the problem is that you don't know what len(train_data) actually is. If its a Sequence subclass then it would be correct.

Comment: True, which is why I think it would be best for them to provide us with the notebook for context.
Also, knowing the size of the dataset would help tune the parameters.

Comment: No, not a notebook, we do not take colab links here since they are not permanent.